# Oracle external tables

Tags: oracle, external-tables

I'm struggling with an Oracle external table, although I researched the Oracle forums. Still, no success.

Let's suppose I have a simple table

```
DESCRIBE PRODUCTS
Name                           Null     Type                                                                                                                                                                                          
------------------------------ -------- --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
ID                             NOT NULL NUMBER                                                                                                                                                                                        
NAME                                    VARCHAR2(30)                                                                                                                                                                                  
VALUE                                   NUMBER(5,2)                                                                                                                                                                                   
DEP                                     VARCHAR2(30)                                                                                                                                                                                  
COUNT                                   NUMBER(3)
```

Then, I created an oracle folder:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE DIRECTORY ext_prod_dir AS 'c:\';
```

I save the content of that table in a .lst file

```
spool c:\products.lst
select p.id || ';' || p.name || ';' || p.value  || ';' || p.dep || ';' || p.count FROM products p;
spool off;

P.ID||';'||P.NAME||';'||P.VALUE||';'||P.DEP||';'||P.COUNT                                                                                                                                
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
1;Settlers of Catan;29,95;Toys;3                                                                                                                                                         
2;DVD Player;82,97;Electronics;2                                                                                                                                                         
3;Red Shirt;12,49;Clothes;3                                                                                                                                                              
4;Black Leather Couch;399,99;Furniture;5                                                                                                                                                 
5;Oak Cofee Table;223,99;Furniture;5                                                                                                                                                     
6;Technodrome;27,99;Toys;4                                                                                                                                                               
7;Oh Cereal;3,95;Foods;1                                                                                                                                                                 
8;Game Console;299,95;Toys;2                                                                                                                                                             
9;Video Game;29,95;Toys;3                                                                                                                                                                
10;Lawn Chair;34,99;Furniture;11                                                                                                                                                         
11;Dog Toy Bone;34,99;Toys;9                                                                                                                                                             
12;Heated Blanket;27,95;Toys;8                                                                                                                                                           
13;Flux Capacitor;27,95;Toys;7                                                                                                                                                           
14;Chocolate Pie;3,14;Foods;7
```

Then I tried to create the external table:

```
CREATE TABLE products_ext 
  (ID NUMBER, 
  NAME VARCHAR2(30),
  VALUE NUMBER(5,2),
  DEP VARCHAR2(30),
  COUNT NUMBER(3)) 
  ORGANIZATION EXTERNAL 
  (TYPE oracle_loader DEFAULT DIRECTORY ext_prod_dir 
  ACCESS PARAMETERS 
      (RECORDS DELIMITED BY NEWLINE 
      FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';'
      MISSING FIELD VALUES ARE NULL 
      BADFILE ext_prod_dir:'products.bad_xt'
      LOGFILE ext_prod_dir:'products.log_xt'

      (ID CHAR(6),
      NAME CHAR(30),
      VALUE CHAR(8),
      DEP CHAR(30),
      COUNT CHAR(3))) 
      location ('products.lst')
      ) REJECT LIMIT UNLIMITED
```

So far so good. Then when I select data from the external table, I got:

```
ORA-29913: error in executing ODCIEXTTABLEOPEN callout 
ORA-29400: data cartridge error 
KUP-00554: error encontered while parsing access parameters 
KUP-01005: syntax error: found "badfile": expecting one of: "column (,reject"
KUP-01007: at line 4 column 7
```

I tried a huge amount of things, but I got variations on this error. Best thing I accomplished was that I got rid of error, but the table was empty. I would be very much indebted If someone with more experience can point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

BADFILE and LOGFILE are not part of the FIELDS clause. So, move them above the FIELDS TERMINATED.

```
CREATE TABLE products_ext
  (ID NUMBER,
  NAME VARCHAR2(30),
  VALUE NUMBER(5,2),
  DEP VARCHAR2(30),
  COUNT NUMBER(3))
  ORGANIZATION EXTERNAL
  (TYPE oracle_loader DEFAULT DIRECTORY ext_prod_dir
  ACCESS PARAMETERS
      (RECORDS DELIMITED BY NEWLINE
      BADFILE ext_prod_dir:'products.bad_xt'
      LOGFILE ext_prod_dir:'products.log_xt'
      FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';'
      MISSING FIELD VALUES ARE NULL
      (ID CHAR(6),
      NAME CHAR(30),
      VALUE CHAR(8),
      DEP CHAR(30),
      COUNT CHAR(3)))
      LOCATION ('products.lst')
      ) REJECT LIMIT UNLIMITED
```

Also, you said when you got rid of the error, the table was empty. Did you check the logfile? If the error is with the VALUE column, then check NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS parameter
in view v$nls_parameters.

```
select * from v$nls_parameters;
```

Check if the decimal marker is indeed a comma. If not either update this parameter or change it in the data file.

Comment: Ok, so I got rid of the error after moving them above the FIELDS TERMINATED, but now the table it's again empty.
In the log file it says KUP-04021: field formatting error for field ID.
What could be wrong with the id field?

Comment: @user3139925 - does your `.lst` file still contain the column headers from your query? `P.ID||'` would error. You should remove the header, or `set heading off` when you generate the file.

Comment: Hey, thanks very much! I removed the header. I replaced the "," character with "." And every row ends with ";". My .lst file looks like 
1;Settlers of Catan;29.52;Toys;3;<br/>
2;DVD Player;82;Electronics;2;<br/>                                                                                                                                                         
...
Now, when I SELECT * FROM products_ext it displays only the first row. A step forward, though. What else could it be?

Comment: @user3139925 - what does the log file say is wrong now?

Comment: Now it doesn't give me any error at all. I will display the log file anyway: Record format DELIMITED BY NEWLINE
  Data in file has same endianness as the platform
  Rows with all null fields are accepted

  Fields in Data Source: 

    ID                              CHAR (6)
      Terminated by ";"
      Trim whitespace same as SQL Loader
And the same thing for NAME, VALUE, DEP, COUNT fields.(the character limit doesn't permit me to post the full log)

Comment: @user3139925 - with the control file from this answer and your data with no header I get 14 rows from the table. Does yours only show you the DVD player? The `NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS` thing might be a red-herring; if your query is using `,` as the decimal separator then the external table will too, it needs to be consistent (for the session anyway). But your log file would show ORA-01722 errors if that was what was wrong now. (Also, consider using `set trimspool on` so you don't need to add a trailing `;`).