# Invalid table name while bulk insert in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to insert values into Oracle table using `Bulk Insert` query but getting below error

```
ORA-00903: invalid table name
00903. 00000 -  "invalid table name"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 4 Column: 5
```

Here is my query

```
BULK INSERT TEST1.STUDENT
    FROM 'C:\Users\Alan\Desktop\STUDENT.txt'
        WITH
(
            FIELDTERMINATOR = '\t',
            ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
);
```

Why is this error coming. Is there some issue with query? Please help. Thanks

Update

I changed by file format to `CSV` and wrote below query

```
LOAD DATA
INFILE 'C:\Users\Alan\Desktop\STUDENT.csv'
INTO TABLE TEST1.STUDENT
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ","
(ID,
NAME);
```

but above query is giving

```
ORA-00928: missing SELECT keyword
00928. 00000 -  "missing SELECT keyword"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 16 Column: 2
```

What is wrong in the above syntax?

Comment: This is not Oracle syntax at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not Oracle syntax at all. If you need to load data from file to table please use either [SQLoader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39886379/oracle-bulk-insert-using-sql-developer) or [External table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23963307/oracle-external-tables) 
Some documentation about [External table](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14215/et_concepts.htm) and [SQLoader](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14215/ldr_concepts.htm)

If you're using SQLDeveloper you can also use import facility.

Please also have a look on that [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6198863/oracle-import-csv-file).

[EDIT}

```
LOAD DATA
INFILE 'C:\Users\Alan\Desktop\STUDENT.csv'
INTO TABLE TEST1.STUDENT
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ","
(ID,
NAME);
```

This is not a query. This is content of control file. Please save it to file load.csv then run `cmd` (or shell if yuo're on Linux) and type:

```
sqlldr user/pass control=load.ctl
```

Some examples you can find [here](http://www.oracle-dba-online.com/sql_loader.htm).